# How can I un-ignore a tag?

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags

[image: prison architect question is greyed out]

I play Prison Architect, and I therefore have favourited the [prison-architect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prison-architect) tag. However, as you can see in the above screenshot, the tag appears to be both favourited and ignored at the same time. I've tried unfavouriting the tag and then favouriting it again to no avail. Is this a bug or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Your ignore list is right under your favourite list on the right - you may have to click 'Edit' on the favourites tag list to view it. I'm pretty sure a tag can be both favourited and ignored, so check if it's not in there. Clicking the star of a tag's description only toggles it from favourite/unfavourite - it doesn't do anything to the ignore list.

Comment: @Robotnik Found it! Thanks very much

Comment: @imulsion - cool, no problem :-). Did that solve your problem with the tag though?

Comment: @Robotnik It did. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

With the design changes to the Favourite/Ignored tags section, this is now a lot easier. For one thing, the Ignored Tags box is now always visible (previously, it was only visible if you clicked 'edit' on the Favourite Tags widget).

From the ignored tag box on the right of the page:

[image: Ignored Tags box]

Either click inside the tag area, or click 'edit':

[image: Ignored Tags box in edit mode]

Then, click the 'x' on the tag to remove it from the list